# Issue with scikit-learn's BaggingClassifier and custom base estimator: operands can't be broadcast together?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, valueerror

I'm trying to use a custom classifier with SciKit-Learn's `BaggingClassifier`, and I'm getting an error which I cannot determine the source of. My classifier object passes `check_estimator()`, and I have no issue with the `fit()` function:

```
model = ensemble.BaggingClassifier(customEstimator, max_samples=1/n_estimators, n_estimators=n_estimators)
model.fit(trainfeat, trainlabels)
model.predict(testfeat)
```

This yields the below error trace. The base estimator itself makes binary predictions, via sigmoid threshold. I know that these values must correspond to the test data, but I don't understand what the three operators are supposed to be? And further, this seems like the error is coming from `BaggingClassifier`, but the issue must be from me, no?

I'm trying to avoid pasting the code for my entire estimator, but it inherits `BaseEstimator` and I only write/overload the functions: `fit`, `predict`, `predict_proba`. Am I missing something in this regard?

I've tried reshaping the features/labels to no avail, didn't even alter the error. I also attempted to have my estimator inherit `ClassifierMixin` but that ended up giving me a slew of new issues.

```
  File "Main_File.py", line 76, in <module>
    model.predict(testfeat)

  File "G:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py", line 310, in predict
    indices.extend(np.where(_predict_binary(e, X) > thresh)[0])

  File "G:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py", line 98, in _predict_binary
    score = estimator.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]

  File "G:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\bagging.py", line 698, in predict_proba
    for i in range(n_jobs))

  File "G:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1003, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):

  File "G:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 834, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)

  File "G:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 753, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)

  File "G:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 201, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)

  File "G:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 582, in __init__
    self.results = batch()

  File "G:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 256, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "G:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 256, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "G:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\bagging.py", line 129, in _parallel_predict_proba
    proba += proba_estimator

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100000,2) (100000,) (100000,2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem arises from the output of `predict_proba` of your `customEstimator`.

Looks like your current implementation return output with a dimension `(n_samples, 1)`, which is not compatible. Make sure your `predict_proba` output's dimension is `(n_samples, 2)` for binary classification problem.